# Packages in python with pip-installed but new projects don't detect package

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Just as a background, I am an R user but learning python:

I have installed python libraries I want to get familiar with (pandas, numpy, Pytorch, tensorflow...), but when I start a new project, it does not detect the packages when I try to import and requests that I install them, even though I definitely did at one point. I am obviously making mistakes when installing them, but don't know what.

I use pip as a package manager if that is relevant

Comment: Open your terminal/command prompt, run 'pip install numpy'. then run 'python', after you see the arrows on left side, type 'import numpy' at the terminal, if it throws an error you haven't properly installed numpy. Let me know if you face any error in any step.

Comment: the command prompt?

Comment: yes..check the updated comment.

Comment: Thanks, it did not throw an error, although my project still does not detect numpy

Comment: That means your python is properly installed.  which editor are you using? if you can, run the file from the command line. suppose the file name is  'main.py', then change directory to the folder(from command line with cd), where the file resides in, then run 'python main.py' does it run?

Comment: The thing is I have no code in my file yet, I am just trying to import (my goal right now is to reproduce and analysis I did in R). Although perhaps I could still try to run it??

Comment: put something simple like print("Hello World"), then run it. if it runs, then try putting 'import numpy' on top(As you previously installed numpy) The first one will check if it is running properly, the second one will show if it can get the package.

Comment: It prints Hello world in the terminal, but import numpy is still throwing an error

Comment: It is very unfortunate,  as your problem is not reproducible, I am not sure if I can test it in my environment. you can try reinstalling python, running through idle, or wait for an expert answer. For now, I will suggest, use google colab. Sorry, I couldn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted installing pip3 and using that in place of pip? I know I had some issues a while back where pip would install my packages for python 2.X and not 3.X.

Comment: usually, windows don't give me those problems, Linux or mac does. But doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: I am on windows. All the things I am reading says since I have python3, I should have pip3, although when I type "pip3 --version" in the terminal, it says pip3 is not defined

Comment: It's the expected behaviour in windows. It usually doesn't keep python 2, only python3 under pip..